# IOS - control-drag of a button is not working

Tags: ios

I have some buttons I am trying to create, and when I try to do a control-drag into the controller, it isn't showing me the options to create configure that button. Any idea what could be wrong? I am just following my first tutorial is its probably something for newbies.

My screen shot is attached.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you opened an incorrect .h file in your assistant editor, you will need to open the correct interface file for the correct view controller you have in your nib

from what i can see is that LearningCenter should not be the interface opened,

You will need to change the assistant view controller to the correct one
Check the screen shot

[image]

Comment: thanks. I wanted to connect the learn button with the learning-center controller so it can eventually go to a screen for that.  How should I accomplish that?

Comment: what is the name of the current controller you have opened in your left side of the xcode?

Comment: I just put together that view with the 4 buttons. But I have not configured any controllers so far. The controller I created was the learningCenter controller. The current controller that is showing on the right side is the LearningController

Comment: thanks, and I kind of don't understand still. I can't reproduce the steps to show that "automaic" pulldown. And I also am not sure why not have the learningCenter controller opened? Should I have the controller opened for which the view is? Is that my main problem?

Comment: Oh got it - duh me. I understand..the view is supposed to be same with the conrtoller :) thanks!!! now it works

Answer (score 1):

just right click on your button from that select last option (New Referencing outlet collections. from that map your .h file . At the time a popup will appear. just enter your button name.